# Escaping JSON returned from an onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, json, onclick, escaping

I am currently having trouble with the JSON being returned from an onclick function. Sometimes the JSON returned from the call is valid and will display correctly, other times it will break due to what is being read as a closing quotation or something similar.

Where the HTML is generated:

```
    newsapi.v2.everything({
q: 'football transfer',
language: 'en',
from: '2020-01-30',
to: '2020-01-31',
sortBy: 'relevancy',
pageSize: 100
}).then(response => {
    var news = response
    var parentNode = document.getElementsByClassName("Content")[0];
    var i = 0; 
    while(i < news.articles.length) {

        var curArticle = JSON.stringify(news.articles[i])

        parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<a href='#' onclick='toggleSide("+ curArticle +")'> <div class='NewsItem newsID"+i+"'> <p> <b>" + news.articles[i].title +  "</b> </p>" +
        "<p> <i>" + news.articles[i].description + "</i> </p>" +
        "<p> <a href='"+ news.articles[i].url +"' target='_blank'>Source</a> </p> <hr> </div> </a> " )
        i++
    }
});
```

The toggleSide function:

```
global.toggleSide = function(newsArticle) {

var newsItems = document.getElementsByClassName("Content").length
var newsElems = document.querySelectorAll(".Content");

if (document.getElementById("Sidebar") == null) {
    if(newsItems > 0) {
        [].forEach.call(newsElems, function(el) {
            el.classList.remove("Content");
            el.classList.add("ContentMinimised");
        });
        var sidebar = document.createElement("div");
        sidebar.setAttribute('id', 'Sidebar');
        document.body.appendChild(sidebar);
        var parentNode = document.getElementById("Sidebar");
        parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div id='NewsInfo'> <br> <h3>" + 
            "<a href='" + newsArticle.url + "' target='_blank' >" + 
            newsArticle.title + "</a> </h3>" +
            "<p>" + newsArticle.author + " — " + newsArticle.source.name + "</p>" +
            "<p>" + newsArticle.description + "</p>" +
            "<img src='" + newsArticle.urlToImage + "' class='NewsImage'>" +
            "<p>" + newsArticle.publishedAt + "</p>" +
            "<p> Content: <br>" + newsArticle.content + "</p>" + "<a href='#' onclick='closeSidebar()'> <img class='CloseButton' src='./close.png' alt='Close'> </a>")
        }
```

Here is a screenshot of the HTML generated. As you can see, some are parsed as fully valid JSON and others are breaking early.

[JSON being passed through HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKz46.png)

Looked at a few ways of escaping JSON but having a hard time applying them to my code. Still very much in the learning stages so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A better way would be not to insert your JSON in the HTML at all. Instead, you can bind an event listener to the element using `addEventListener`, it would be a lot cleaner. Here is an example:

```js
// Not doing a request here, but for the purpose of this demo...
requestCallback({"status":"ok","totalResults":10,"articles":[{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Nytimes.com"},"author":"Motoko Rich","title":"‘We’re in a Petri Dish’: How a Coronavirus Ravaged a Cruise Ship - The New York Times","description":"More than three days passed before Japan imposed a quarantine. That delay and other missteps helped produce the largest outbreak of the virus beyond China.","url":"https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/22/world/asia/coronavirus-japan-cruise-ship.html","urlToImage":"https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/02/22/world/22ship-reconstruct-still/22ship-reconstruct-still-facebookJumbo.jpg","publishedAt":"2020-02-22T10:23:00Z","content":"She was told that it was up to the Japanese health ministry, and that no tests were available on board. After a day passed, her husband, John, called the U.S. Embassy in Tokyo and tried to convince an official that everybody needed to be tested.\r\nWere in a pe… [+1119 chars]"},{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Tomsguide.com"},"author":"Philip Michaels","title":"Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra benchmarks: The new Android phone to beat - Tom's Guide","description":"The Galaxy S20 Ultra benchmarks are in, and there's a new standard for Android phones","url":"https://www.tomsguide.com/news/galaxy-s20-ultra-benchmarks","urlToImage":"https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/yQ3UVFY7KyVXW8gREVjpP7-1200-80.jpg","publishedAt":"2020-02-22T07:00:00Z","content":"The Galaxy S20 Ultra still can't top Apple's latest iPhones for performance. But the gap between the leading Android phone and Apple's pace-setting flagships is more narrow than it was before Samsung's latest phone came along.\r\nThat's our takeaway after we ha… [+6593 chars]"},{"source":{"id":"cnn","name":"CNN"},"author":"Helen Regan, CNN","title":"Fears over containing novel coronavirus grow as cases outside China spike - CNN","description":"Concerns are growing over the global spread of the novel coronavirus after a spike in cases outside of mainland China among people with no connection to China or the city of Wuhan, ground zero for the outbreak.","url":"https://www.cnn.com/2020/02/22/asia/novel-coronavirus-covid-19-update-intl-hnk/index.html","urlToImage":"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200222123543-coronavirus-seoul-medic-super-tease.jpg","publishedAt":"2020-02-22T06:09:00Z","content":"Hong Kong (CNN)Concerns are growing over the global spread of the novel coronavirus after a spike in cases outside of mainland China among people with no connection to China or the city of Wuhan, ground zero for the outbreak.\r\nWorld Health Organization (WHO) … [+6697 chars]"},{"source":{"id":"cnbc","name":"CNBC"},"author":"Reuters","title":"Trump plans to raise issue of religious freedom with Indian Prime Minister Modi, official says - CNBC","description":"Modi's government has faced large scale-protests at home and criticism abroad for enacting a citizenship law that is seen as discriminating against Muslims.","url":"https://www.cnbc.com/2020/02/22/trump-to-raise-issue-of-religious-freedom-with-indias-modi-official.html","urlToImage":"https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/105993990-1561731409119gettyimages-1152448893.jpeg?v=1582349930","publishedAt":"2020-02-22T05:39:00Z","content":"U.S. President Donald Trump will raise the issue of religious freedom in India during his meetings with Prime Minister Narendra Modi next week, a senior administration official said, a sensitive subject for the Indian government.\r\nModi's government has faced … [+2829 chars]"},{"source":{"id":"fox-news","name":"Fox News"},"author":"Victor Garcia","title":"Laura Ingraham mocks Dems' inability to guarantee same-day Nevada results: 'Are we a Third World country?' - Fox News","description":"Do Saturday's Nevada Democratic primary caucuses even matter? That's the question Fox News host Laura Ingraham raised Friday night, on the eve of the voting -- as many other questions hovered over the contest.","url":"https://www.foxnews.com/media/laura-ingraham-bernie-is-sure-to-win-tomorrow-in-nevada","urlToImage":"https://cf-images.us-east-1.prod.boltdns.net/v1/static/694940094001/81ab5314-6aa2-4ab7-a31f-1b1d7dc30576/78a3c690-cfb5-4608-ac03-2baf258d8318/1280x720/match/image.jpg","publishedAt":"2020-02-22T05:37:29Z","content":"Do Saturday's Nevada Democratic primary caucuses even matter? That's the question Fox News host Laura Ingraham raised Friday night, on the eve of the voting -- as many other questions hovered over the contest.\r\n\"And it looks like Democrats could be facing a r… [+1773 chars]"}]});

function requestCallback(news) {
    var parentNode = document.querySelector(".Content");
    news.articles.forEach(function (article) {
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = '#';
      link.innerHTML = 
           '<div class="NewsItem">'
         +   '<p><b>' + article.title +  '</b></p>'
         +   '<p><i>' + article.description + '</i></p>'
         +   '<p><a href="' + article.url + '" target="_blank">Source</a></p><hr>'
         + '</div>';
      parentNode.appendChild(link);
      link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        toggleSide(article); 
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent jumping to the top of the page
      });
    });
}

// I don't know what your toggleSide does because you didn't post HTML,
// so this is just to show you you can use the provided article
function toggleSide(article) {
  document.getElementById('Sidebar').innerHTML =
             '<h3>' + article.title +  '</h3>'
         +   '<p><i>' + article.author + ' — ' + article.source.name + '</i></p>'
         +   '<p>' + article.description + '</p>'
         +   '<img src="' + article.urlToImage + '"/>'
         +   '<p>' + article.content + '</p>';
}
```

```css
/* Irrelevant to the question */ *{box-sizing:border-box}body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}.Content{width:60%}.Content>a{display:block}#Sidebar{background:#fff;padding:.5em;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;height:100%;width:40%;overflow-y:auto;border-left:1px solid #bbb;box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}img{display:block;width:100%}
```

```html
<div class="Content"></div>
<div id="Sidebar">← Click on an article</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for! I figured there had to be a clearer option to use than the onclick given the crazy arguments being overtly passed through the HTML. Thank you for the clear explanation and rundown, will definitely look at applying event listeners in the future.